# How to run a loop on an array, combine the results and set them to a variable

Tags: ruby, loops, foreach

I have this `array`: `['John', 'Michael', 'Siri']`. How can I run an `each` loop on them and add a text to each "part" of the array and at the end "combine" the result of the loops and set/assign the result of all `each` to a `variable`?

By that I mean, I do:

```
array = ['John', 'Michael', 'Siri']
array.each do |a|
  text = "#{a} here"
  # Results would need be =>
  # John is here
  # Michael is here
  # Siri is here
  @new_string = text # => Which would need to be "John is here Michael is here Siri is here"
end
```

I have done the code above, but `@new_string` becomes only `Siri is here` and if I move the `@string` out of the loop, like below, it becomes `John is here`, so basically it takes only one of them and "assigns" it to `@new_string`.

```
array = ['John', 'Michael', 'Siri']
array.each do |a|
  @text = "#{a} here"
end
@new_string = @text
```

I tested with `[0]+[1]+[2]` and it kind of worked, but the problem is that I would not know the size of my array. It can be 2 items or it can be 100 items.

Comment: Take a look at [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join).

Comment: Another way: `("%s is here " * array.size)[0..-2] % array #=> "John is here Michael is here Siri is here"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way

```
array = ["John", "Michael", "Siri"]
your_variable = array.map { |name| "#{name} is here" }.join(" ")
```

It's basically a transformation, you want to add something to each element of a collection (use `map` for that). Lastly, join them up.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ursus. I appreciate it a lot

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Can be done by

```
 array.map { |x| x + ' is here' }.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

More concisely:

```
%w{ John Michael Siri}.collect{|s| s+" is here"}.join(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the `array = ['John', 'Michael', 'Siri']`, the problem with your code is that the variable has a scope inside of the loop so it is not accessible after the loop ends.

The solution is to declare the variable before.

```
@new_string = '' # initialize outside the loop
array.each do |a|
  text = "#{a} here "
  @new_string += text # note +=
end
@new_string #=> "John here Michael here Siri here "
```

For the second code, the problem is the same:

```
@new_string = '' # initialize outside the loop
array = ['John', 'Michael', 'Siri']
array.each do |a|
  @new_string += "#{a} here " # note +=
end
@new_string #=> "John here Michael here Siri here "
```

As you can see string ends with a space, to avoid it populate an array then join as showed in previous answers:

```
@new_string = [] # initialize outside the loop
array = ['John', 'Michael', 'Siri']
array.each do |a|
  @new_string << "#{a} here" # note +=
end
p @new_string = @new_string.join(' ') #=> "John here Michael here Siri here"
```

Side note:

```
# comments in ruby starts with #
```